# Displaying first 5 options as default in select2

Tags: jquery-select2, dropdown

I am trying to display the first 5 options as default in rendering select2.

```
Select countries
____________

America
Canada
England
France
Spain
```

I made it multiple and used selected, so it could display but not as straightforward like the above.

How can I set it up like this?

I used the open option, so it displays them like above.

```
$('#id').select2('open')
```

However, when I click on anywhere on the screen, it closes. How can I keep it open all the time?

Comment: Could you please show us some code.

Comment: @ascsoftw, added the code, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that your Dropdown HTML is like below:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="s1" style="width: 300px">
        <option value="1">America</option>
        <option value="2">Canada</option>
        <option value="3">England</option>
        <option value="4">France</option>
        <option value="5">Spain</option>
</select>
```

If you want to always keep Open the dropdown, you can use following code. This prevents the closing by overriding the callback method.

```
$(doucment).ready(function() {
var list = $('#s1').select2({
  closeOnSelect: false,
}).on("select2:closing", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).on("select2:closed", function(e) {
  list.select2("open");
});


list.select2("open");
});
```

Please see the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofnbq5at/)

Comment: @a2a Glad to help. Could you please also upvote the answer.